# How do I set a dead zone for my Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: pc, controllers

How do I set a "dead zone" for my Xbox 360 wired controller ([reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYMzf.jpg)).

**Clarification: I meant for use with my PC.**

Additional information: The reason I want to do this is because the joystick is beaten up from a lot of usage and now it suffers from "ghosting" which basically means it moves slightly and it can easily screw things up while in-game. For those of you who don't know what a "dead zone" is it is basically a small area (from the center of the joystick) that is *dead* so it will stop moving and stop ghosting. Google will probably yield more information on the specifics though.

Comment: It's not possible from your xbox itself. It could be possible with hardware modifications, but that would be really out of scope for this site.

Comment: I should clarify I meant for use with my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://mattbrett.com/blog/videogames/2005/configuring-your-xbox-360-controller-for-windows/) this is possible with [pinnacle game profiler](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/). I haven't tested it out, so I'm not sure if it works. Give it a try :).
Also it would be great if you could post your results back, I think a lot of people would find it useful information in the future.

Answer (score 4):

[Durazno](https://code.google.com/p/magical-tools/wiki/Durazno), is a very tiny [open-source](https://code.google.com/p/magical-tools/source/browse/trunk/Durazno/Durazno/Readme.txt) XInput wrapper that lets you customise your controller's properties on a per-game basis. It includes deadzone fine-tuning, among other things.