# How do I set custom diagonal deadzones for my Xbox 360 controller on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, windows-10

I'm playing a fighting game (Guilty Gear Strive) and the angle to get diagonal outputs on my left joystick is very tight on this game. For example, to get a top right diagonal output, I need to input a flick which is quite near the 45 degree angle from the vertical/horizontal otherwise the input gets registered as an up/right.

I know of Steam controller configuration and some programs which allow you to tune the deadzones but they only allow you to change your inner/outer circular deadzone.

How do I map a range of angles on the joystick to a set of different angles(i.e. widen the range of diagonal input)? Games like Rocket League have this form of deadzone tuning in their settings, but the game I'm playing does not.

Below is an image to illustrate my problem.
[image]

**EDIT:** Turns out Steam controller configuration already allows you to do this (kind of). You can map the joystick to a dpad using the "style of input" dropdown on the joystick. You can then adjust the range of the diagonal input. However you lose the analog aspect of the joystick so the original question still stands.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade and great first question! Unfortunately, as it stands now, your question is technically off-topic. If you'd like guidance, you could always ask on [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) or in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge).

Comment: I only asked in this SE site because of a similar question (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-do-i-set-a-dead-zone-for-my-xbox-360-controller). Do you think perhaps superuser.com would be better to ask this on? @Tacoタコス

Comment: If a recommendation is all you are looking for, then this question would be off-topic here, and on Super User as well.  But, if you remove the recommendation part of your question, and make this just "how can I set a custom digital deadzone on my controller", then I think it is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which part of question is asking for a recommendation. If you could clarify, I will edit the question accordingly. ^_^

Comment: I've edited and trimmed the question, please let me know if it's correct now.